# Using System.Uri to remove redundant slash

Tags: c#, .net, url

I have a condition in my program where I have to combine a server (e.g. `http://server1.my.corp/`) that may or may not have an ending slash with a relative path (e.g. `/Apps/TestOne/`). According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Uri` should...

> Canonicalizes the path for hierarchical URIs by compacting sequences such as /./, /../, //,...

So when I do something like `var url = new Uri(server + relativePath)`, I'd expect it to take what would otherwise be `http://server1.my.corp//Apps/TestOne/` and remove the double slash (i.e `//` -> `/`), but `ToString`, `AbsolutePath` and various options still show the redundant/duplicate slash. Am I not using `Uri` right?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at the constructors for the [Uri class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx). You need to specify a base Uri and a relative path to get the canonized behavior. Try something like this:

```
var server = new Uri("http://server1.my.corp/");
var resource = new Uri(server, "/Apps/TestOne/");
```

Comment: A word of caution to anyone using this constructor overload: be careful if your `server` URI contains any resource path component (e.g. "http://server1.my.corp/Apps/"). The resource path will be truncated if it is not terminated with a slash ("/"). See the Remarks section of the `Uri(Uri, string)` constructor [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.-ctor#system-uri-ctor(system-uri-system-string)).