# Remove additional slashes from URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, slash

In `ASP.Net` it is posible to get same content from almost equal pages by URLs like 
`localhost:9000/Index.aspx` and `localhost:9000//Index.aspx` or even `localhost:9000///Index.aspx`

But it isn't looks good for me.

How can i remove this additional slashes before user go to some page and in what place?

Comment: Remove at server side or at client side ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, i think better will be from server

Comment: If your url includes the http:\\ part, you're screwed with all of the current answers. Don't just replace, build the url with care.

Answer (score 6):

Use this :

```
url  = Regex.Replace(url  , @"/+", @"/");
```

it will support n times

[image]

Comment: What tool are you using in that screenshot?

Comment: @KellenStuart, a bit late to the party, but that looks like LINQPad.

Answer (score 6):

see

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19689870

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91.aspx#Examples

> You need to specify a base Uri and a relative path to get the canonized behavior.

```
Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm");
Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is not that pretty but very easy

```
do
{
    url = url.Replace("//", "/");
}
while(url.Contains("//"));
```

This will work for many slashes in your url but the runtime is not that great.

Comment: This won't work if URL string contains something like this 'https://examplewebsite.com//some-page'
it will remove '//' from 'https://' and URL wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Remove them, for example:

```
 url = url.Replace("///", "/").Replace("//", "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Regex.Replace("http://localhost:3000///////asdasd/as///asdasda///asdasdasd//", @"/+", @"/").Replace(":/", "://")`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code snippets for combining URL segments, with the ability of removing the duplicate slashes:

```
    public class PathUtils
    {

        public static string UrlCombine(params string[] components)
        {
            var isUnixPath = Path.DirectorySeparatorChar == '/';

            
            for (var i = 1; i < components.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Path.IsPathRooted(components[i])) components[i] = components[i].TrimStart('/', '\\');
            }

            var url = Path.Combine(components);

            if (!isUnixPath)
            {
                url = url.Replace(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar, '/');
            }
            return Regex.Replace(url, @"(?<!(http:|https:))//", @"/");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in PowershellCore

```
$Uri -replace  "(?<!:)/{2,}", "/"
```