# Removing extra-slashes from Url in ASP.NET MVC5,

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am doing the SEO-optimization of my site and currently working with URLs. I've already removed the last slash and added redirection from

> http://example.org to http://www.example.org.

Now I want to remove all extra-slashes from my URL:
This URL :

> www.exaple/about///graduation

should redirect to

> www.example/about/graduation.

I found similar questions in SO, but they seems to be asked in context of pure ASP.NET. [Using System.Uri to remove redundant slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689778/using-system-uri-to-remove-redundant-slash)

[Remove additional slashes from URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30483947/remove-additional-slashes-from-url)

How can I implement the same in MVC5?

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004223/remove-multiple-forward-slashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Code-behind redirect in your Global.asax like this;

```
   protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string requestUrl = Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_URI"];
    string rewriteUrl = Request.ServerVariables["UNENCODED_URL"];
    if (rewriteUrl.Contains("//") && !requestUrl.Contains("//"))
        Response.RedirectPermanent(requestUrl);
}
```

I got this code from [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004223/remove-multiple-forward-slashes), I hope that's useful to you =]

Comment: Don't use this code! The code above has a nasty bug. If you are trying to do an error redirect (e.g. by using the httpErrors config section) it will get fed in something like `/Error/NotFound?404;http://localhost:81/e/e/e/e`, see the `//` in `http://` and then redirect to the original url, causing an infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Then I would recommend you comment on the original post, where I got the code from

Comment: I did also comment on the original post.